# how to pass text box value in show function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to pass the text box value in show function

```
<div id="userComment">
    <input type="text" name="comment" id="comment" placeholder="Enter comment here">
    <button type="submit" class="postComment" onclick="show()" value="<?php echo $postId ?>">POST</button>
</div>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? This is a very simple task, I can only assume you haven't taken the time to do any research...

Comment: You can get the textbox by its id and then get its value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you marked the question with `jQuery`, you can register a listener and pass the value to `show` then. No need for setting it with `onclick` on the element.

```js
$(function() {
    $(".postComment").click(function() {
        show($("#comment").val());
    });
});

function show(value) {
    console.log(value);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="userComment">
  <input type="text" name="comment" id="comment" placeholder="Enter comment here">
  <button type="submit" class="postComment">POST</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can write code like this,this way is very concise.

```
<div id="userComment">
    <input type="text" name="comment" id="comment" placeholder="Enter comment here">
    <button type="submit" class="postComment" onclick="show($('#comment').val())" value="<?php echo $postId ?>">POST</button>
</div>
```